# Problem regarding non-abelian groups and their $Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a non-abelian group and $a,b\in G$ such that for every $c\in G\setminus Z(G)$ we have $acb=bca$, then $a,b$ commute, i.e. $ab=ba$.

So far, I have noticed that if we suppose that $ab\ne ba$, then $b\notin Z(G)$, therefore $ab^2=b^2a$. Analogously, we get $a^2b=ba^2$. But I did not yet manage to obtain a contradiction.

Later edit: I had to correct the initial statement; it is $acb=bca$. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a^{-1}b \in Z(G)$, then $a^{-1}ba=aa^{-1}b=b$, so $ab=ba$.

If $a^{-1}b \notin Z(G)$, then apply the hypothesis with $c=a^{-1}b$ : it gives you $aa^{-1}bb=ba^{-1}ba$, so $b=a^{-1}ba$, so $ab=ba$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $a^{-1}b$. If $a^{-1}b \in Z(G)$ then $aa^{-1}b=a^{-1}ba$. Therefore $ab=ba$.

If $a^{-1}b \notin Z(G)$ then apply the hypothesis to give $a(a^{-1}b)b=b(a^{-1}b)a$. So $b^{2}=ba^{-1}ba$ and $ab=ba$.